# Why does my SELECT query take so much longer to run on the web server than on the database itself?

Tags: sql, select, coldfusion, ibm-midrange

I'm running the following setup:

Physical Server
Windows 2003 Standard Edition R2 SP2
IIS 6
ColdFusion 8
JDBC connection to iSeries AS400 using JT400 driver

I am running a simple SQL query against a file in the database:

```
SELECT
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    ....
FROM    LIB/MYFILE
```

No conditions.

The file has 81 columns - aplhanumeric and numeric - and about 16,000 records.

When I run the query in the emulator using the STRSQL command, the query comes back immediately.

When I run the query on my Web Server, it takes about 30 seconds.

Why is this happening, and is there any way to reduce this time?

Comment: How much data is it exactly? What is the bandwidth between the DB and the web server?

Comment: are you using anything other than straight SQL? i.e. cfqueryparam or anything else?

Comment: @MattBusche - no CFQUERYPARAM used - just SELECT [list of columns] FROM [LIB].[FILENAME]

Comment: @ppeterka not sure of exact bandwidth between DB and web server, but they are in the same domain and sit in a rack right next to each other. This application runs hundreds of queries all day and they all run in milliseconds. This one query is oddly slow.

Comment: My past experience with AS400 databases and the JT400 driver is that overall it was always much slower than other JDBC databases (like MS SQL Server). In the end, I set up a SQL Server Integration  Services scheduled job to import the required AS400 tables into SQL Server, and queried the SQL Server database from ColdFusion.

Comment: If you run another query that is similar, do you get the same delay?

Comment: I also found that many AS400 tables are not indexed very well, if at all. This significantly impacts performance when querying and retrieving multiple records.

Comment: It might be as simple as you are selecting too much data.  What happens if you put in a where clause so that you are selecting less?

Comment: @cfvonner I disagree entirely about speed.  In our benchmark tests, we normally find DB2 for i tables return better response times than our SQL Server best, much to the astonishment of our SQL Server folk.  When this is not true, it has often been because the SQL should have been done differently, or there should have been better indexes.  Indexes are much cheaper on IBM i, and often under-utilized.  But of course this is highly dependent upon the speed and workloads of the systems in question, and YMMV.

Comment: I tried running a similar query on the same table with some conditions. It is quicker (likely because it is bring back less results), but is still not at an acceptable level, as this other query is used for an ajax call. This main query is used to cache the data for easy and quick filtering on the entire data-set for other applications that filter the data differently.

Comment: @WarrenT you might be correct about iSeries DB2 database performance normally. My experience has been the opposite. However, it may be the SunGard system (formerly HTE) that is the culprit in my case. The client interface is designed primarily for working with single records, not multiple records. As such, there are few if any indexes on the tables. My code pulls multiple records as part of an integration with a GIS application - and that's where performance was very poor.

Comment: i Navigator can help you look to see what indexes have been advised, and will let you query the system plan cache to look for queries that may not be performing well. The index advisor is a big help, but in some cases you should use judgement before blindly taking all of it's advice.  But indexes on the i are very cheap compared to other DBMS. Even dozens of indexes over a table is generally not considered a big deal by top DB2 for i DBA's.

Comment: @cfvonner remember, this system has been architected from the ground up, and refined at every level, for over 30 years with the primary goal of improving multiuser business application (largely database) performance and reliability. This is the harware line that IBM built Watson on. While there are many factors involved in configuration and performance of dissimilar systems... If you take the same dollars to purchase, and the same skill level to configure & program, I believe most i experts would be truly shocked if we were not able to run circles around SQL Server in general.

Comment: @cfvonner that said, SQL server does have some special features designed for GIS applications, doesn't it?

Comment: @WarrenT I appreciate the insight on AS400 and DB2. In my case, I am not the administrator of the iSeries system, and requests to add indexes have been denied because the administrator does not want to do anything that might jeopardize the turnkey SunGard system that runs on it, since it is critical to the operation of the organization. I've talked to other folks who have run into the same problems working with AS400 databases in ColdFusion.

Comment: @cfvonner I feel your pain.  Sadly this lack of expertise and understanding is all too common.  One of the great strengths of the platform is that it is so automated (from a DBA point of view) that most shops have felt they dont need a DBA, or sometimes hardly any IT staff at all to manage it, or without much training for it.  If they understood what they have, they'd know that it's not a problem.  I have run into this on many kinds of systems.  I wish there was some way to help you more.  But this is a personnel / education problem, and sad.  (But helping educate is why I'm here ;)

Answer (score 4):

While I cannot address whatever overhead might be involved in your web server, I can say there are several other factors to consider:

This may likely have to do primarily in the differences between the way the two system interfaces work.

Your interactive STRSQL session will start displaying results as quickly as it receives the first few pages of data.  You are able to page down through that initial data, but generally at some point you will see a status message at the bottom of the screen indicating that it is now getting more data.

I assume your web server is waiting until it receives the entire result set.  It wants to get all the data as it is building the HTML page, before it sends the page.  Thus you will naturally wait longer.

If this is not how your web server application works, then it is likely to be a [JT400 JDBC Properties](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahh%2Fjdbcproperties.htm) issue.

If you have overridden any default settings, make sure that those are appropriate.

In some situations the OPTIMIZATION_GOAL settings might be a factor.  But if you are reading the table (aka physical file or PF) directly, in its physical sequence, without any index or key, then that might not apply here.

Your interactive STRSQL session will default to a setting of *FIRSTIO, meaning that the query is optimized for returning the first pages of data quickly, which corresponds to the way it works.

Your JDBC connection will default to a "query optimize goal" of "0", which will translate to an OPTIMIZATION_GOAL setting of *ALLIO, unless you are using extended dynamic packages.  *ALLIO means the optimizer will try to minimize the time needed to return the entire result set, not just the first pages.

Or, perhaps first try simply adding `FOR READ ONLY` onto the end of your SELECT statement.

### Update: a more advanced solution

You may be able to bypass the delay caused by waiting for the entire result set as part of constructing the web page to be sent.

Send a web page out to the browser without any records, or limited records, but use **AJAX** code to load the remainder of the data behind the scenes.

Use large block fetches whenever feasible, to grab plenty of rows in one clip.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you need to remember, the i saves the access paths it creates in the job in case they are needed again. Which means if you log out and log back in then run your query, it should take longer to run, then the second time you run the query it'll be faster. When running queries in a web application, you may or may not be reusing a job meaning the access paths have to be rebuilt.

If speed is important. I would:

1. Look into [optimizing the query](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzajq%2Fqodm.htm). I know there are better sources, but I can't find them right now.
2. Create a stored procedure. A stored procedure saves the access paths created.

Comment: If he is using such a simple query, do you really think building an access path is likely to be the issue here?  There is no WHERE clause, no ORDER BY clause, nor anything else that would complicate matters.  It would seem he is either accessing an unkeyed file, or if defined with a key, there is already a keyed access path built for it.

Comment: @WarrenT The file is indeed keyed - a one column key on the unique identifier.

Comment: @WarrenT very true... I missed exactly how simple it was. I assumed more than there actually was.

Comment: Even using keyed access, the index already exists, the file is not large, the access path should not be the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

With only 16000 rows and no WHERE or ORDER BY this thing should scream.  Break the problem down to help diagnose where the bottleneck is.  Go back to the IBM i, run your query in the SQL command line and then use the B, BOT or BOTTOM command to tell the database to show the last row.  THAT will force the database to cough up the entire 16k result set, and give you a better idea of the raw performance on the IBM side.  If that's poor, have the IBM administrators run Navigator and monitor the performance for you.  It might be something unexpected, like the 'table' is really a view and the columns you are selecting might be user defined functions.

If the performance on the IBM side is OK, then look to what Cold Fusion is doing with the result set.  Not being a CF programmer, I'm no help there.  But generally, when I am tasked with solving multi-platform performance issues, the client side tends to consume the entire result set and then use program logic to choose what rows to display/work with.  The server is MUCH faster than the client, and given the right hints, the database optimiser can make some very good decisions about how to get at those rows.